# Get value from another controller using cshtml razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm kinda new and was wondering if this was possible. I have two different pages that run on two different controllers.

Example controller1 and controller2

In my current view page I'm using @model controller1
But I need to get a value from controller2 is there a way? I thought I could have two model statements but guess I couldn't.

Comment: You can use  viewmodel

Comment: Depending on what you need, there is always way.
It also depends on what limitations do you have, for instance if you are able to change model for controller1, or controller2, or controllers themselves, or if you are able to create 3rd controller which will serve your task.
Are you able to use JQuery or Ajax?
There are lot's of ways and approaches, but first you need to describe your task in more details first, so that we know where are your limitations, or what exactly you are trying to achieve. It is hard to give full answer to your question right now, but answer would be yes for sure.

Comment: You can also use Nested model structure, where you'll put 1st model and second model in one single model, and pass that one single model to the view, and then access them by Model.FirstModel and Model.SecondModel, but that can be considered as a bad approach in many cases, for instance if you are trying to retrieve just one single property from that model, and you are loading 1000 of other properties that might slow down page loading, and that is not the only case where it can be wrong. that's why I wonder what is the actual task.